# Side limits of a function with a cusp (does the limit exist at the cusp? is it it differentiable at the cusp?)

Tags: calculus, limits

I seem to recall from one of my Calculus lectures that a function with a cusp on its graph does not have a limit at the cusp because the side limits are different. This in turn means that the function is not differentiable at the cusp.

But consider the following function:
$$f
\begin{cases}
x^2, &0 < x \leq 2 \\
(x- 4)^2, &2 < x < 4
\end{cases}
$$

[image]

When I check the side limits, they seem to match:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x\to 2^- & x \to 2^+\\
\hline
\begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
1.9 & 3.61 \\
1.99 & 3.9601 \\
1.999 & 3.996001 \\
\end{array}
&\begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
2.1 & 3.61 \\
2.01 & 3.9601 \\
2.001 & 3.996001 \\
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

This seems to suggest that there is a limit at $2$, which would suggest $f$ is differentiable at $2$.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps what was meant is that the one-sided **difference quotient** limits are different at the cusp

Comment: What is a difference quotient?

Comment: Pkease ead the Wikipedia [Difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient) article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong.

It is correct to say that functions with a cusp are not differentiable (using the standard definition) at the cusp. However, differentiability is not a *requirement* for the limit to exist.

Instead, *if* a function $f$ *is* differentiable at some point $x_0$, *then* $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ exists, but not the other way around. Just because there is a limit does not mean that the function is differentiable at that limit.

Consider for example $f(x)=|x|$. Obviously, $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)=0$, but $f'(0)$ is undefined.

On the other hand, if the limit *does not* exist at a point $x_0$, *then* the function will not be differentiable at $x_0$; e.g. - $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\implies\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\text{undefined}\implies$$f$ not differentiable at $0$.

Summary:

- not differentiable $\implies$ maybe limit exists, maybe not
- differentiable $\implies$ limit exists
- limit does not exist $\implies$ not differentiable
- limit exists $\implies$ maybe differentiable, maybe not

Comment: So how would I justify that this function is not differentiable?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure my Calculus professor said, at some point, that "$f$ is non-differentiable at $a$ means $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$ does not exist". The contrapositive of that is that if the limit does exist at that point, then it is differentiable at that point, is it not? And doesn't that contradict what you're saying? Or am I misunderstanding something? If there's a contradiction, are you certain he's wrong?

Comment: @Calculemus What your professor said is correct. $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$ is a definition of the derivative at $x$. If the derivative at $x$ is undefined, then so is the limit expression defining the derivative and vice-versa. However, this is the limit of the *derivative*, not the limit of the *function* itself. The limit in your example is the limit of a *function*, not its derivative.

Comment: @Calculemus To show that a function $f$ is not differentiable at $x$, you can look at the limit of its derivative. If the limit of the derivative does not exist at $x$, then $f$ is not differentiable at $x$.